# Returning a value of column A if column B has corresponding unique values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, unique

Example dataframe

```
index     sample 
1           x                    
1           x
1           x
1           y
2           z
2           z
2           z
3           x
3           y
3           y
3           z
```

I would like to create a loop where it will go through the index list and return it if the corresponding sample values are different. I'm trying something like this but I am not too sure how to implement it.

```
for i in 1:length(index){
if(index == 1) {
check for sample values{
if there are more than one distinct value{ 
print(index)
else{
index + 1}}}}}
```

Ideally the vector returned would be
[1] 1 3

Since index == 2 consist of all the same values

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `aggregate` and `subset`:

```
subset(aggregate(sample ~ index, function(x) length(unique(x)), data = df), sample > 1)$index

[1] 1 3
```

Generally, using loops in R is quite inefficient and most of the time there is better (and faster) alternative.

Here is the data I used

```
df <- structure(list(index = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), sample = c("x", 
"x", "x", "y", "z", "z", "z", "x", "y", "y", "z")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(index) %>% filter(n_distinct(sample)>1) %>% pull(index) %>% unique
[1] 1 3
```